# why can function without return type in /usr/include/c++/5/bits/fstream.tcc

Tags: c++

following code make me confused, it has no return type:

```
  template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
    basic_filebuf<_CharT, _Traits>::
    basic_filebuf() : __streambuf_type(), _M_lock(), _M_file(&_M_lock),
    _M_mode(ios_base::openmode(0)), _M_state_beg(), _M_state_cur(),
    _M_state_last(), _M_buf(0), _M_buf_size(BUFSIZ),
    _M_buf_allocated(false), _M_reading(false), _M_writing(false), _M_pback(), 
    _M_pback_cur_save(0), _M_pback_end_save(0), _M_pback_init(false),
    _M_codecvt(0), _M_ext_buf(0), _M_ext_buf_size(0), _M_ext_next(0),
    _M_ext_end(0)
    {
      if (has_facet<__codecvt_type>(this->_M_buf_locale))
    _M_codecvt = &use_facet<__codecvt_type>(this->_M_buf_locale);
    }
```

the code is in `/usr/include/c++/5/bits/fstream.tcc`

Comment: Its a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It's a constructor for the class template `basic_filebuf<_CharT, _Traits>`. Notice the function name is the same as the class name, only the template arguments don't need to be repeated. Constuctors don't have return types.